# The Slides is showing on mobile app but not appearing on the web app on React Native(Am Using Expo)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I don't Know why The Slides are not showing on the web app but in the mobile app everything is good as expected.

**If someone can help me because I need it for My graduation Project :**

The mobile app Screenshot:
[mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXBCY.png)

The Web app Screenshot:
[web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLais.png)

### The Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
} from "react-native";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const BASE_UNIT = 8;

const slides = [
  {
    title: "Secured, forever.",
    description:
      "Secured Curabitur lobortis id lorem id bibendum. Ut id consectetur magna. Quisque volutpat augue enim, pulvinar lobortis.",
    img:
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-ui-kit/dribbble2react/master/vpn-app/assets/images/welcome.png",
  },
  {
    title: "Encrypted, forever.",
    description:
      "Encrypted Curabitur lobortis id lorem id bibendum. Ut id consectetur magna. Quisque volutpat augue enim, pulvinar lobortis.",
    img:
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-ui-kit/dribbble2react/master/vpn-app/assets/images/encrypted.png",
  },
  {
    title: "Privacy, forever.",
    description:
      "Privacy Curabitur lobortis id lorem id bibendum. Ut id consectetur magna. Quisque volutpat augue enim, pulvinar lobortis.",
    img:
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-ui-kit/dribbble2react/master/vpn-app/assets/images/privacy.png",
  },
];

const Dots = ({ scrollX }) => {
  const dotPosition = Animated.divide(scrollX, width);

  return (
    <View style={styles.dotWrapper}>
      {slides.map((item, index) => {
        const opacity = dotPosition.interpolate({
          inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
          outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
          extrapolate: "clamp",
        });

        return <Animated.View key={`dot-${index}`} style={[styles.dot, { opacity }]} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const SlideTexts = ({ slideIndex }) => {
  const slide = slides[slideIndex];

  return (
    <>
      <Animated.Text style={styles.title}>{slide && slide.title}</Animated.Text>
      <Animated.Text style={styles.description}>{slide && slide.description}</Animated.Text>
    </>
  );
};

const SlideImages = ({ scrollX }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        scrollEnabled
        decelerationRate={0}
        scrollEventThrottle={BASE_UNIT * 2}
        snapToAlignment="center"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }], {
          useNativeDriver: false,
        })}>
        {slides.map((item, index) => (
          <View key={`img-${index}`} style={styles.slideWrapper}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.img }} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.slideImage} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const Vpn = () => {
  const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollX.addListener(({ value }) => {
      setSlideIndex(Math.floor(value / width));
    });
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SlideImages scrollX={scrollX} />
      <View style={styles.bottomWrapper}>
        <SlideTexts slideIndex={slideIndex} />
        <Dots scrollX={scrollX} />
        <Animated.View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.75} style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => {}}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>GET STARTED</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  slideWrapper: {
    width,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  slideImage: {
    width: width / 1.5,
    height: "100%",
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: BASE_UNIT * 3,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  description: {
    textAlign: "justify",
    fontSize: BASE_UNIT * 2,
    marginHorizontal: BASE_UNIT * 3,
    marginVertical: BASE_UNIT * 2,
  },
  bottomWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  buttonTitle: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    marginHorizontal: BASE_UNIT * 6,
    marginVertical: BASE_UNIT,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#00A9FC",
    borderRadius: BASE_UNIT * 2,
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    alignItems: "center",
    margin: BASE_UNIT * 3,
  },
  dotWrapper: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginVertical: BASE_UNIT,
  },
  dot: {
    flex: 0,
    width: BASE_UNIT,
    height: BASE_UNIT,
    margin: BASE_UNIT / 2,
    borderRadius: BASE_UNIT,
    backgroundColor: "gray",
  },
});

export default Vpn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having height as a percentage in styles.slideImage behaves weird on the web. If you give it a number the image appears, but to give it the right number you would have to calculate the view height using onLayout and another state variable. You could avoid this by just giving slideWrapper a flex of 1

```js
slideWrapper: {
    flex:1,
    width,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
```

After fixing this, I noticed the dots werent visible. I fixed with this:

```js
dot: {
    // flex: 0,
    width: BASE_UNIT,
    height: BASE_UNIT,
    margin: BASE_UNIT / 2,
    borderRadius: BASE_UNIT,
    backgroundColor: "gray",
  },
```

Comment: I noticed that on the web the scrollview was wasnt containing itself to the screen's width so I made changes to fix that. Afterwards, I released that on the web swipe gestures arent picked up for  the scrollview so i decided to allow navigation to happen with the dots, which prompt me to switch to a flatlist. [Check it out](https://snack.expo.dev/QdS1vEUA3)

Comment: Now is better than the previous but I see just the half of the pictures on the slide